# "There are workers in/on an assembly line"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between these two sentecnes?

> "There are workers **in** an assembly line."

and

> "There are workers **on** an assembly line."

Or are these two interchangeable?

Because I looked up my dictionary and it has the following two examples with similar usages.

First example

> ...a man who works **on** an assembly line.

Second example

> The worst job I had was standing **in** a production line assembling chairs in a furniture factory form 7am-4pm.

My guess is that the usage of **on** means something is done by a particular instrument or a machine.

The usage of **in** means something is done there.

Comment: I don't think there is any practical difference in meaning.

Comment: Great! I'm just not so sure why if there is no difference or if there is a difference? These two prepositions **in** and **on** are too similar to me.

Comment: Well, as you say, you work **on** a machine positioned **in** a line - but in your original sentence there is no practical difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the United States, it is not particularly idiomatic to say that you work "in" an assembly line. Working "on" an assembly line sounds far more natural to me.

Generally speaking, you work "in" a location and "on" a task or project. An assembly line isn't quite either of those, although I think of it as closer to a task/project than a location. Maybe that's why "on" is the preposition typically used in this phrase.

You can't really compare phrases with the verb "work" with those using the word "stand." In most parts of the United States, for example, you stand "in" line (what the Brits call a queue), although in New York City and maybe a few other places, they say stand "on" line. In any case, "standing in/on a production line" isn't a very common phrase when compared to the more often-heard "work on an assembly line."

Comment: btw, the second example is with a note "UK written" in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You work **on** an assembly line.

The noun "assembly line" *collocates* with the preposition "on".

[This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20*%20an%20assembly%20line&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) is convincing:

[image: Ngram for work * an assembly line]

Comment: Fantastic! This is of assistance to me. It looks the same case with "work on a/the production line" given the collocation from this powerful tool.